# MySQL optimizer index choice for simple select query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I have a table called `PendingExpense` with a few simple columns but a lot of rows. I'm working on some queries for paginated GET responses, but running into some confusion working with the queries and the MySQL optimizer seemingly making a senseless decision to do a full index scan for the `ORDER BY` clause before filtering from the `WHERE` clause.

This is on MySQL version 8.0.23.

`PendingExpense` DDL (note, a companyId and loginCredentialId is how I specify a user in my schema):

```sql
create table PendingExpense
(
    ID                        bigint   auto_increment primary key,
    LOGINCREDENTIALID         int      null,
    COMPANYID                 int      null,
    DATE                      datetime null,
    -- ... other rows that don't pertain, e.g. amount, status, type, state, country, merchant
)

create index IN_PendingExpense_COMPANYID_ASC_LOGINCREDENTIALID_ASC
    on PendingExpense (COMPANYID, LOGINCREDENTIALID);

create index IN_PendingExpense_LOGINCREDENTIALID_ASC
    on PendingExpense (LOGINCREDENTIALID);

create index IN_PendingExpense_Date
    on PendingExpense (DATE);
```

Then here are the two queries I'm comparing, they are identical other than the index hint. I'm including the execution plans for both immediately below:

Query 1 (no hints):

```sql
explain analyze select id from PendingExpense
where COMPANYID = 1641 and LOGINCREDENTIALID = 2451
order by date DESC, id DESC
limit 101; -- takes 5.5 seconds
```

```
-> Limit: 101 row(s)  (cost=2356102.00 rows=101) (actual time=2292.676..4474.843 rows=101 loops=1)
    -> Filter: ((PendingExpense.LOGINCREDENTIALID = 2451) and (PendingExpense.COMPANYID = 1641))  (cost=2356102.00 rows=105) (actual time=2292.675..4474.818 rows=101 loops=1)
        -> Index scan on PendingExpense using IN_PendintExpense_Date (reverse)  (cost=2356102.00 rows=5660) (actual time=0.088..4371.774 rows=1491859 loops=1)
```

Query 2 (index hint):

```sql
explain analyze select id from PendingExpense use index (IN_PendingExpense_COMPANYID_ASC_LOGINCREDENTIALID_ASC)
where COMPANYID = 1641 and LOGINCREDENTIALID = 2451
order by date desc, id desc
limit 101; -- .184 seconds
```

```
-> Limit: 101 row(s)  (cost=9722.30 rows=101) (actual time=38.255..38.267 rows=101 loops=1)
    -> Sort: PendingExpense.`DATE` DESC, PendingExpense.ID DESC, limit input to 101 row(s) per chunk  (cost=9722.30 rows=27778) (actual time=38.254..38.259 rows=101 loops=1)
        -> Index lookup on PendingExpense using IN_PendingExpense_COMPANYID_ASC_LOGINCREDENTIALID_ASC (COMPANYID=1641, LOGINCREDENTIALID=2451)  (actual time=0.046..35.410 rows=14170 loops=1)
```

Essentially, I'm confused why MySql chooses to do the full index scan first before filtering on companyId / loginCredentialId when the index already exists for those two, causing significant inefficiencies. I'd much prefer to not have to specify index hints in my code/queries for cleanliness. I was under the impression MySQL generally chooses to run the where clause filtering first, especially if an index already exists for it.

Any help / hints / insight would be appreciated here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This composite, covering, index should be perfect for that query:

```
INDEX(COMPANYID, LOGINCREDENTIALID,   -- in either order
      date, id)    -- last, in this order
```

The first two columns are tested via `=`, allowing the INDEX rows to be precisely found.

The last two rows can be scanned backward to perfectly go through the index.

**'Covering'**

Since *all* the necessary rows are in the index (hence "covering" aka "Using index"), the data's BTree does not need to be touched.

The entire table lives in a B+Tree; it is ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Hence, it is efficient to lookup a single row or range of rows based on the PK.

Each "secondary" index is a very similar B+Tree.  It contains all the column(s) specified in the index, plus (silently) all the column(s) of the PK.  That is, with

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),  INDEX(foo, bar)
```

the secondary index is really a B+Tree indexed by `(foo, bar, id)`.  When those columns are all that is needed for a `SELECT`, the index is "covering" and *only* that B+Tree is looked at.  If you need other columns, then `id` (in this example) is used to reach into the data's BTree to find the other columns, based on `id`.

**"Full table scan" or "Full index scan"**

If no index (PK, nor secondary) is useful locating the requested row(s), the query will do a "full table scan", checking each row for whether it is relevant.  Similarly, it may use a "full index scan" when a "covering" index is being used.

Continuing with the example above (and assuming another column `x` not in any index),

```
SELECT *        FROM t WHERE id=5;   -- point query
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE foo=5;  -- covering
SELECT bar      FROM t WHERE foo=5;  -- covering
SELECT x        FROM t WHERE foo=5;  -- well indexed (but not covering)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE bar=5;  -- full index scan (covering but slow)
SELECT *        FROM t WHERE bar=5;  -- full index scan (plus lookup)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE x=5;    -- full table scan
SELECT *        FROM t WHERE x=5;    -- full table scan
```

(These examples are ordered, fastest first.)

`SELECT COUNT(*) ...` returns 1 row.  `SELECT * ...` potentially returns many rows, so potentially slower.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you expand on "the data's BTree does not need to be touched"? Does that mean to say that since all necessary rows for the query are in the index, we won't need to do a full table scan?

Comment: @J.LaF _ I added some more.

Answer (score 1):

Your optimized query would be one that includes the where clause FIRST, then secondarily the order by.  So I would have an index on

```
( COMPANYID, LOGINCREDENTIALID, DATE, ID )
```

Company and credentials covers the where clause.  Then the date and ID for the order by clause.

Comment: that seems like an overly complex index to maintain for table with a lot of entries, I think inserts and updates would be hurt in the long run

Comment: @J.LaF - But will you be changing values a lot?  It is usually better to have the SELECT running a lot faster, at the expense of the INSERTs/UPDATEs running a little slower.

Comment: Updates are made often to these entries, and a large goal of mine is keeping api latency low as possible.